# send email on a change in a cell value with message from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, sendmail

I am new to google scripts. I have a range where the cells in a column change. If the number of a cell from that column is above zero then the script has to send an email with the message being the content from a cell in the same row with the updated cell(that is, different column) Let's say If a value in column I changes then automatically it has to send an email with the message contained in the same row but column F for example. Please see below, I would appreciate some help.

```
function SendValue() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dividend");
    var values = sheet.getRange("I2:I").getValues();
      //var values1 = sheet.getRange("G2:G").getValues();
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
      if(values[i]>0){
      results.push(sheet.getIndex([+i+2]+"G"));  
        // +2 because the loop start at zero and first line is the second one (I2)
      }
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail('sxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'EX-DIVIDEND', results );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`getValues()` returns a 2 dimensional array, or more accurately an array of arrays, even if one of the dimensions is 1. `values[i]` is not a value but rather an array representing the i row of the range. You will need to acess that array to get at the cell at a particular column in that row.

replace `if(values[i]>0)` with `if(values[i][0]>0)`

I suspect that `results.push(sheet.getIndex([+i+2]+"G"));` should be `results.push(sheet.getRange("G"+(i+2)).getValue());` as getIndex() doesn't take arguments and that looks like it is meant to be A1 notation.

However there is a better option than trying to construct A1Notation. 
`getRange()` supports using numbers to refer to rows and columns. `getRange(7, i+2)` is a better choice.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)

Comment: it seems   > 'results.push(sheet.getValue("G"+(i+2)));' is not recognising 'getValue'.<     I tried to have it as:    > 'if(values[i][0]>0){
        results.push(sheet.getSheetValues(+(i+2), 2, +(i+2), 7));//("G"+(i+2))); 
        // +2 because the loop start at zero and first line is the second one (I2)
      }
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail('s.mandis@gmail.com', 'EX-DIVIDEND',     results );
  };' , the emails is sent but the message contains everything after the range (i+2,G).< How can I fix it. Thanks

Comment: I missed a call. i fixed the code and added an alternative to constructing an A1Notation string.